# Python: Searching for exact filename

Tags: python, text, io

In searching for a HTML within my current directory, if the name contains any substring it will assume that file exists and continue the operation instead of saying the file doesn't exist. Say I have a file "protocolHTTP.html" - in testing to make sure "protocol.html" throws an error, it doesn't. It just continues with the operation of the program.

I would like to make sure the filename matches exactly. Here's what I have:

```
for file in glob.glob('*.html'):
        if protocolFile in file:
                with open(file) as f:
                        contents = f.read()
        else:
                print "Could not locate '" + protocolFile + ".html'"
                sys.exit(1)
```

Any ideas or further steps I could check to validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code does the same thing as:

```
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()
else:
    print 'Could not locate {0}'.format(filename)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Aha, that was what I was looking for! Mine does the same thing essentially, however isfile() will validate the entire name, whereas if 'file' will not and will consider the substring valid input. If I use "protocol" in any way it will validate, however if I use "pineapple" it will not. Appreciate the input!

Comment: @Signus Then I haven't understood you well. Do you want a whole file match or just a partial file match? If you want just a partial why not use: `glob.glob('*partial*.html')`, and let the `glob` function do all the work?

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to get a full filename match, and I was using 'in' like Brian pointed out is not an equality check. I was trying to fix that problem, which you helped me with.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is not an equality check, it is a collection membership check. Look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) and scroll down to after the bulleted list for the discussion of `in`.

```
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar'
True
>>> 'foo' in 'foo'
True
>>> 'foo' in 'bar'
False
```

Not that it's a good idea to loop when searching for one file, but if you had done the following instead it would have worked.

```
if '{}.html'.format(protocolFile) == os.path.basename(file):
```

So, in general, go with Viktor's approach. But make sure you also understand how `in` works.